# Use any() in OrientDB

Tags: special-characters, orientdb, any

I want to use any() in a search query, which can contain also some special characters.
When I try this:

```
select from MyVertex where any() contains '%user%'
```

it returns the expected result. The problem is when I am have a date-time column, like "2016-01-25 13:51:58". When I type

```
any() like '%2016-01%'
```

the query return no results. I think the problem is with the character "-", because if I put '%2016%', it works fine.

Comment: What version of OrientDb are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with 2.2.5 and it worked for me

```
create class MyVertexDate extends V
insert into MyVertexDate(data1,data2) values ("2016-01-25 13:51:58","2016-01-25 13:51:58"),("2016-01-25 13:51:58","2016-01-25 13:51:58")
select from MyVertexDate where any() like "%2016-01%"
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have 2.1.19. I tested your query in my database, and it works. But my query doesn't.  That column is of DATETIME. If I don't put the  "where" clause, I have values like "2016-01-25 13:51:58". But " where any() like '%2016-01%' "; does not return any result.

Comment: I have reproduced your problem if that column is of datatime. Can you open an issue on githhub ?